# SSAS mdx query penalty when run as a regular user vs ran as server administrator

Tags: sql-server, ssas, ssas-tabular

I'm running a MDX query on a MS SSAS Tabular instance using two different users. The first is a Server Administrator and the second one is a member of the Reading security Role. The query runs in ~0.8 seconds under the Server Admin while the unprivileged user runs it in ~6  seconds.

Any ideas on what's causing this performance penalty?

Here are a few more details: 
- the exact same MDX is ran by both users. Checked with the profiler;
- the Reading role has no DAX row filters defined;
- I ran the query multiple times on the two accounts and the execution times remained consistent;
- running MS SQL Server 2012 (Enterprise).